# Screen flow pre populating custom "new opportunity" screen

Tags: account, screen-flow

In account, when the "new opportunity" button is pushed and the new opportunity pop up form comes up, it has "account name" pre-populated. My understanding is that if I want other things to be pre-populated like "billing address" I need to make a custom screen flow and attach it to a new button. I've been going through youtube and some websites and what I'm failing to figure out what the process is to make the "account name" etc... appear in a custom new opportunity form or if it's even possible for it to pull that information from account or if users are just going to have to manually fill that in.

Comment: Are you not able to fetch the information to pre-populate it on the Screen Flow or do you still want to pre-populate that information on the pop-up form?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the data what ever you want to prepopulate using getrecords and passing the accountid before adding the screen element and using that data inside your screen element in the default value option .

[image]